# SUM CASE adding from joined table instead main table

Tags: mysql

I have a query that retrieves from a customer:

- sum of time expent on his tickets (every ticket can have 1 or more interventions)
- average resolution time
- category of each ticket

The query:

```
SELECT SUM(f.duree) as total_time, SUM(timestampdiff(second, t.datec, t.date_close))/COUNT(distinct t.rowid) as average_resolution, COUNT(distinct t.rowid) as tickets, 
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'WITHOUT_MAINTENANCE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sin_mantenimiento,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'WITH_MAINTENANCE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as con_mantenimiento,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'WITH_BILLABLE_MAINTENANCE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as con_mantenimiento_facturable,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'NO_BILLABLE_COASER_WARRANTY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as no_facturable_garantia_coaser,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'OFERTADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ofertado
                FROM llx_ticketsup as t
                JOIN llx_element_element as ee on ee.fk_source = t.rowid
                JOIN llx_fichinter as f on f.rowid = ee.fk_target
                WHERE t.fk_soc = 47 AND t.fk_statut = 8
```

where

- llx_ticketsup is main tickets table
- llx_fichinter is table where interventions from tickets are stored
- llx_element_element is table between tickets and interventions

My problem is, if one ticket has more than 1 intervention, on sum of category types to know how many are from this category and how many from the other, it sums interventions instead tickets. For example, if query returns 2 tickets and they have a total of 6 interventions, it returns 6 tickets of category `WITHOUT_MAINTENANCE`, instead 2 tickets of category `WITHOUT_MAINTENANCE`.

Whats wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothings 'wrong' that's expected behaviour try using a sub query to get the duration. Something like

```
SELECT (select sum(f.duree) from llx_fichinter as f on f.rowid = ee.fk_target) as total_time, SUM(timestampdiff(second, t.datec, t.date_close))/COUNT(distinct t.rowid) as average_resolution, COUNT(distinct t.rowid) as tickets, 
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'WITHOUT_MAINTENANCE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sin_mantenimiento,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'WITH_MAINTENANCE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as con_mantenimiento,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'WITH_BILLABLE_MAINTENANCE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as con_mantenimiento_facturable,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'NO_BILLABLE_COASER_WARRANTY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as no_facturable_garantia_coaser,
                SUM( CASE t.category_code WHEN 'OFERTADO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ofertado
                FROM llx_ticketsup as t
                JOIN llx_element_element as ee on ee.fk_source = t.rowid

                WHERE t.fk_soc = 47 AND t.fk_statut = 8
```

If that doesn't work add sample data and expected result to the question as text so we can play with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this query is returning me `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'on f.rowid = ee.fk_target)`

Comment: Sorry the on in the sub query should be a where. Sample Data?